# pagination - xpath for a crawler in python

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

i'm actually working on a crawler using scrapy in python, and i almost done, i just have a little problem.
The website using a pagination like that:

```
<div class="pagination toolbarbloc">
            <ul>
                    <li class="active"><span>1</span></li>
                    <li><a href="...">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="...">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="...">4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="...">5</a></li>
                    <li><a class="end" href="...">>></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

So i try to catch the "href" to the balise li just after li with class "active".

I try something like that:

```
next_page_url_xpath = '//div[@class="pagination toolbarbloc"]/ul/following-sibling::li[@class="active"]/a/@href'
```

but it didn't work : IndexError: list index out of range

I just begin with xpath and i know it's simple but after read lot of doc', i'm not successful with that.

Thanks a lot for those who help me !

Comment: `'//div[class="pagination toolbarbloc"]//a[@href]/@href'` I think this one will work well. Select a's href attribute which a has href attribute and is a sub node of div with class "pagination toolbarbloc"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below expression:

```
//div[@class="pagination toolbarbloc"]/ul/li[@class="active"]/following-sibling::li/a/@href
```

Note that you missed `@` in `[class="pagination toolbarbloc"]` and `li` is not a sibling of `ul`

Comment: Thanks i edit ! i remember i try ure way and it didn't work but now it's okay ! thanks a lot